# Objective c - Macro with NSDictionary as parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macros

I have a method that I want to execute only in some cases (for example I don't want to execute it in debug mode..)
This method has two parameters: `NSString` and `NSDictionary`

For example this class method:

```
+ (void)doSomethingWithString:(NSString *)str andDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dic;
```

So I want to define a macro, and disable it when no needed.
Something like this:

```
#define METHOD_ENABLED 

#ifdef METHOD_ENABLED
    #define MACRO_METHOD(_STR, _DIC) [SomeClass doSomethingWithString:_STR andDictionary:_DIC];
#else
    #define MACRO_METHOD(_STR, _DIC)
#endif
```

and to use it I call:

```
MACRO_METHOD(@"a string", [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"object" forKey:@"key]);
```

Is this how I should to it?? Can I even have a macro with NSDictionary as a parameter?

Comment: [doSomethingWithString:_STR andDictionary:_DIC] is invoked with object instance or class?

Comment: so what do you do with @"a string" since there's no action taken with it? What is it needed for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Nothing wrong with what you're doing as long as you guarantee that `_STR` evals to a string and `_DIC` truly evals to a dictionary. This type of macro is often used for debug/release/version conditional compilation.

BTW, with recent Clang compilers you can simplify `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"object" forKey:@"key"]` to `@{@"key":@"object"}`

Comment: Yes, using __name is better then _name for macro. Many system definitions have _NAME format.

Answer (score 0):

In Object Oriented programming macro is an element of evil. It is a bad approach to use macros while having all the OOAD techniques on your hand. I would do it this way if you really have to stick to macros:

set a setting in some global singleton:

```
globals.needToDoSomethingWithStringAndDictionary = MACRO_ENABLED; // where macro is bool
```

and then wherever you may need invoke:

```
[SomeClass doSomethingWithString: aString andDictionary: aDictionary];
```

while guard is within the very method:

```
+(void) doSomethingWithString aString andDictionary: aDictionary
{
   if ([globals sharedGlobals].needToDoSomethingWithStringAndDictionary)
    {
    // do your stuff
    }
}
```

This gives you full control on the code while debugging and makes your code maintenance easy!

Comment: Nonsense. Apple's SDK's contain thousands of macros that work in C, Objective-C, C++ and Objective-C++. @Eyal's issue isn't a math problem where precedence could be screwed with an errant parenthesis. And you have a problem with macros but espouse a global variable / singleton?